Stop model.generate
I'm using TextIteratorStreamer to generate text as stream
and I use Thread to run model.generate
thread = Thread(target=model.generate, kwargs=generation_kwargs)
thread.start()

I want to introduce a cancel_event = asyncio.Event() and check if cancel_event.is_set() in the streamer loop to stop model.generate consuming GPU resources, How can I stop model.generate? Do I need to kill the  thread? how?

You can create a class that should handle the cancelling without the need to kill the thread. Something like this might work:
import asyncio
from threading import Thread
from transformers import StoppingCriteria

class StopCriteria(StoppingCriteria):
    def __init__(self, event):
        self.event = event

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.event.is_set()

cancel_event = asyncio.Event()
generation_kwargs['stopping_criteria'] = [StopCriteria(cancel_event)]

thread = Thread(target=model.generate, kwargs=generation_kwargs)
thread.start()

# your existing code

cancel_event.set()

If you want the thread to finish before cancelling it you could use:
thread.join()

